# django-admin.py doens't work on Windows Server 2012

Tags: python, django, windows

I'm not an expert on Python, however, I've been trying to setup a project on Windows Server 2012 on IIS.

When I've tryed to run 'django-admin.py startproject teste' I always got an error like this:

[image]

I've tryed the command in the following ways:

```
django-admin.py startproject teste
python django-admin.py startproject teste
C:\Python37\Scripts\django-admin.py startproject teste
```

And I've tryed put the django-admin.py file on my folder..

My environment variables are like this:

[image]

Can someone help me on this, please?

Comment: Could you post the full traceback i.e mostly the end of the traceback.

Comment: sorry @jackotonye , I've updated my post.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can upgrade django since this has been resolved in `Django>=1.8` 
 https://github.com/django/django/commit/b07aa52e8a8e4c7fdc7265f75ce2e7992e657ae9

```
pip install Django --upgrade
```